# Should I upgrade to Extra Class

Tags: united-states, license

I've held an Advanced Class license for almost 20 years now. I've recently been kicking around the idea of biting the bullet and upgrading to Extra. I know they lifted the code requirement. Part of me wants to stay Advanced because I have the pride and knowledge that, even though I've never made a CW contact ever, I studied hard and passed my code requirement to earn my license. There is a small nagging part of me that feels like I would be cheating not passing the 20wpm test to move up to Extra. Other than the nominal additional bandwidth, is there any real advantage to upgrading my license?

73's
Jim

Comment: You've answered your own question: if you (or I) upgraded from Advanced to Extra then we could operate the entire bands. And Lance is correct, there's no real answers. IMO, all you are going to get here is opinions.

Comment: I realize that. I guess that is kind of what I was looking for. Opinions of fellow Hams.

Comment: If you changed your question to something along the lines of "what are the advantages and disadvantages of upgrading to Extra class from Advanced class?" then your question would be less opinion-based, and therefore might be reopened.

Comment: [Here are some SE reminders about asking good questions](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: From [the Tour](https://ham.stackexchange.com/tour): `Not all questions work well in our format. Avoid questions that are primarily opinion-based, or that are likely to generate discussion rather than answers.` ... `Don't ask about ... Questions that are primarily opinion-based, Questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer`

Comment: Do they still send that nice certificate to put up on the wall?  That was the reason I wanted to upgrade, many moons ago.  I already have the shortened callsign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently went through exactly the same thing.  I take a lot of pride in having that 13wpm code reflected in my license.

I don't think there is a real answer to your question because it is subjective.

I decided to upgrade to Extra a few months ago.  There is also a lot of pride in reaching the pinnacle, going as far as you can.  And since your license records reflect your "Prev. Op. Class", having "Advanced" there will always show anyone who looks that you have the 13wpm accomplishment.

Comment: Good point. I know there isn't a real definite answer. Was mostly looking for others opinions and experiences. I know there was a real stigma at one time around the no code tech class license. Believe it not when I first got my license in the mid 90's there was guys that wouldn't talk with anyone with an N3 call. Which was stupid in my opinion for a group trying to grow their ranks. I changed my call to a 2x2 as soon as I was able. Didn't know if the same type of thing existed with "no code" extra class license holders but I guess there really would be no way to tell.

Comment: Going to Extra has a negative as well -- there will be no more amateur licenses to conquer.  Of course, said half in jest, I have talked with a number of hams over the last 15 years who have voiced that very lament.  Maybe we should all lobby the FCC (in the US) to invent new higher level licenses including topics like working with Maxwell's Equations using Differential Forms (http://users.aims.ac.za/~solomon/akason.pdf).

Comment: @JimMiller You might want to ask this on one of the ham forums. This question is likely going to be closed for [the reasons listed here](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @JimMiller  That's an interesting story about the 1x3 calls.  I was also first licensed in the 90's and got an N9 call but my first license class was Tech Plus.  I don't recall anyone asking if I was "code" or "no code" at the time, but I suppose it could have happened.  I upgraded to Advanced a couple of months later but kept my 1x3.  I finally got a 1x2 earlier this year.

Comment: You could always go for an FCC Radiotelegraph Operator License, which requires copying Morse at 20 wpm.